# Radius in making border is given from inside instead of outside?

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, android-styles, layer-list

I am using below XML for creating border for a `TextView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/padding_4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

When I give radius as `<corners android:radius="@dimen/padding_4dp"/>`, it gives radius to corners but from inside, not from outside. So, as a result, corners remain sharp from outside. Like below:
[image]

Am I doing wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Other items you have added in `layer-list` are `missing corners`, add it as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/padding_4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/dark_gray" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/padding_4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/padding_4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the remaining two item also add a corner radius.